# If Time Updated At Greater Than X do

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think I'm having a brain freeze here but I cannot figure out the best way to do this... Thanks in advance for the help.

I have a some fields in my location table are updated by an external script every 5 minutes. If they're not updated for more than 1 hour, an email will be sent out to the site admins.

That was reasonably straightforward getting a list of dead locations:

```
 scope :not_responding, lambda {
    where('last_heartbeat < ?', Time.now - 1.hour )
  }
```

What I'm stuck on should be very simple.... All I want to do is change the styling of the location name so it's red if it's not responding.

```
%td
  - @locations.each do |locations|    
    = if ('locations.last_heartbeat < ?', Time.now - 1.hour )  
      red
    -else
      green
```

But that throws an error (unexpected ',')

Can anyone suggest how to move this into my model??

-- UPDATED --

I'm not sure if this is a bug or what but I'm seeing some bizarre results.

Using answer below, I've added this:

```
def not_responding?
    last_heartbeat < (Time.now - 1.hour)
  end
```

And call using:

```
- if location.not_responding?
  red
- else
  green
```

However, this gave me an error about '<' being undefined.

In the end, I had to do this to get it to work. All seems ridiculous....

```
 def not_responding
   last_heartbeat <=> (Time.now - 1.hour)
 end
```

And in the view:

```
- if (hotspot.not_responding_two == -1)
  red
- else
  green
```

Does not make sense as the follow test was ok:

```
def test?
  Time.now > (Time.now - 1.hour)
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be something like this:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  def not_responding?
    last_heartbeat < (Time.now - 1.hour)
  end
end
```

I threw in a question mark because this is a Boolean method. And in your view:

```
%td
  - @locations.each do |location|    
    -if location.not_responding?
      red
    -else
      green
```

You need to call a method on the location object, and in this case you're calling the one we just defined, which will return true or false depending on when the last heartbeat was.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Had to put 'self' infront of not_responding but it's throwing an error: "Comparison of Symbol with Time failed"??

Comment: `self` is definitely not the object that has not_responding? defined on it, so I don't know what method you're calling on what in this case.

Comment: oh. Without self.not_responding? I get an error undefined method `not_responding?

Comment: Yeah, you might want to gist your controller, model, and view code and update your original question with a link or something, since I'm a bit confused as to what you have going on at this point.

Comment: Realised what I was doing wrong... Was calling in view incorrectly. Beginners mistake. Sort of working although it's now complaining "undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass"